# c# net core 3.1 razor pages how to use image class

Tags: c#, .net, razor, google-api, razor-pages

Here is what i have:
A client wants me to add a dynamic image to a view. That image is a satellite view from google. I have managed to navigate the google API's to get a working url: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:red|lat,lng&center=lat,lng&zoom=18&maptype=roadmap&key=API-KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:red%7Clat,lng&center=lat,lng&zoom=18&maptype=roadmap&key=API-KEY)

This will render an image with all the needed markings and region/zoom/bounding... that the client wants.

What i need:
I could just send that to the src attribute in an <img> tag client side, however, that means that the API-KEY would also end up client side, bad idea. What i am trying to do is 'download' the image to the server in the OnGet method, then convert it to base64 and place that hex as the src attribute for the image tag. To do this i need to be able to use an Image class and i am not having any luck finding and class related to imaging (Image, Bitmap...) Wonderig where i should be looking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Nuget package [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/).  It contains classes like `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, similar to the old .NET Framework classes.

I use it for various bits of image processing and find it works well - and it works cross-platform.

Comment: That doesn't work for my Razor .NET Core website. I says not supported. I tried an million ways. Reason being is that library only works on MS platforms. CORE is supposed to work on Linux and Android etc.

Comment: @JustJohn Yes indeed it is Windows only.  I use SkiaSharp for non-Windows platforms, but is a totally different API so although it works on other platforms, it is not a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As @bfren said above using the `System.Drawing.Common` package contains all that i need for the imaging, however, i will post my full answer to how i got it working:

```
  using System.Drawing;

  ...
  ...
  ...

  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl.ToString());
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);


  MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();
  bitmap.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
  byte[] imageBytes = imgStream.ToArray();

  return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Note: this works perfectly, but remember to drop it in an ajax call, images can be big.

Comment: Great, glad it worked - I suggest adding a few `using` statements in there in your actual code to make sure things are correctly disposed of afterwards.